# Communication link failure in ssis

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

What is the reasons for package failures of 'Communication link failure'
 and how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, [disabling TCP/IP Chimney Offloading](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951037) was the preferred solution.

However, [according to this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006769), today you should solve your problems more easily using SQL Server options.